# Vuejs dynamic data names

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

Is there a way to dynamically change data names based on other data names? Here is my example.

Say I have these data elements.

```
export default {
 data: function() {
   return {
     speed: "Standard",      
     speed_enabled: false,
     flex_enabled: false,
   };
 },
```

While the user interacts with the front end, I pull in additional `speed` data, in the form of different names. ex. `Priority`, `Expedited` etc.

When I do this I want to change the names of the other data elements. Something like this:

```
export default {
 data: function() {
   return {
     speed: "Standard",      
     {{this.speed}}_speed_enabled: false,
     flex_enabled: false,
   };
 },
```

Something along those lines.. so `speed_enabled` becomes `expedited_speed_enabled` and `priority_speed_enabled` etc. etc.

Is this possible?

EDIT: here is all my code.. maybe someone can figure out how to pass different data to the same component.

Here is my parent component `speeds.vue`:

```
<template>
  <v-app>
    <v-container fill-height>
      <v-layout row wrap align-center>
        <v-flex xs8 class="mx-auto">
            <h1 class="display-1 mont bold fix-title-height pb-3">FBA Shipping Settings</h1>
            <v-tabs icons-and-text centered color="purple darken-3" dark class="elevation-12">
              <v-tabs-slider color="green lighten-1"></v-tabs-slider>

              <v-tab :key="speed" @click="setStandard">
                Standard
              </v-tab>

              <v-tab :key="speed" @click="setExpedited">
                Expedited
              </v-tab>

              <v-tab :key="speed" @click="setPriority">
                Priority
              </v-tab>

              <v-tab-item :key="standard" >
                <speed_details></speed_details>
              </v-tab-item>              

              <v-tab-item :key="expedited">
                <speed_details></speed_details>
              </v-tab-item>

              <v-tab-item :key="priority">
                <speed_details></speed_details>
              </v-tab-item>

            </v-tabs>
         </v-flex> 
     </v-layout>
    </v-container>   
  </v-app>
</template>

<script>
import speed_details from '../components/speed_details.vue';
import {dataShare} from '../packs/application.js';
import axios from 'axios';

export default {
  data: function() {
    return {
      speed: "Standard"
    };
  },
  components: {
    speed_details
  },
  created() {
    console.log("this should get hit at the beginning and what's speed? " + this.speed);
    dataShare.$emit('speed', this.speed);
  },
  methods: {
    getSpeedInfo() {
      axios.get('https://bc-ship-trimakas.c9users.io/return_speed_info', {params: {speed: this.speed}}).then(response => {
        const speed_info = {
          speed_enabled: true,
          fixed_rate_amount: response.data.fixed_amount,
          // this.fixed_enabled = response.data.fixed;
          // this.flex_enabled = response.data.flex;
          // this.flex_above_or_below_amount = response.data.flex_amount;
          // this.percent_or_dollar = response.data.flex_dollar_or_percent;
          free_enabled: response.data.free,
          free_shipping_amount: response.data.free_shipping_amount
        };
        dataShare.$emit('speed_info', speed_info);
      });
    },
    setStandard() {
      this.speed = "Standard";
      dataShare.$emit('speed', this.speed);
    },
    setExpedited() {
      this.speed = "Expedited";
      dataShare.$emit('speed', this.speed);
    },
    setPriority() {
      this.speed = "Priority";
      dataShare.$emit('speed', this.speed);  
    },    
  }
};
</script>

<style>


</style>
```

And then my child component `speed_details.vue` that is the same across all three tabs:

```
<template>
  <v-card flat class="lightblue" :resize="moveIcon">
    <v-form ref="form" v-model="valid" lazy-validation>   

      <v-layout row wrap>
        <v-flex xs7>
          <v-switch 
            :label="'Enable ' + speed + ' Shipping'"
            :v-model="speed_enabled"
            color="purple darken-3"
            @change="enableAndDisable"
            ></v-switch>
        </v-flex>
      </v-layout>

      <v-layout row wrap>
        <v-flex xs7>
          <v-switch 
            label="Enable Flex Rate Shipping?" 
            :disabled="flex_switch_disabled" 
            v-model="flex_enabled" 
            color="purple darken-3"
            @change="killFixed, removeFlexAmount"
            ></v-switch>
        </v-flex>
        <v-flex>
          <v-tooltip top>
            <v-icon slot="activator" color="purple darken-3" class="fix_icon">info</v-icon>
            <span class="body-2">You can enable fixed or flex rate shipping but not both</span>
          </v-tooltip>
        </v-flex>
      </v-layout>

      <v-layout row wrap class="move-up">
         <v-flex xs1>
          <v-select
            :disabled="!flex_enabled"
            append-icon=""
            color="purple darken-3"
            :items="fee_type"
            v-model="percent_or_dollar"
            label="$ or %"
            single-line
            auto
            hide-details
          ></v-select>
        </v-flex>

        <v-flex xs8>                      
          <v-text-field
            :disabled="!flex_enabled"
            type="number"
            color="purple darken-3"
            label="Shipping Amount Above or Below FBA Fees"
            v-model="flex_above_or_below_amount"
            class="push-right"
          ></v-text-field>
        </v-flex>
        <v-flex xs1 v-bind="icon_adjust" class="push_down">
          <v-tooltip top>
              <v-icon slot="activator" color="purple darken-3" class="fix_icon">info</v-icon>
              <span class="body-2">This amount will either increase or decrease(-) the fulfillment amount from Amazon.
              </span>
            </v-tooltip>
        </v-flex>
      </v-layout>

      <v-layout row wrap>                    
        <v-flex xs7>
          <v-switch 
          label="Enable Fixed Rate Shipping?" 
          :disabled="fixed_switch_disabled" 
          v-model="fixed_enabled" 
          color="purple darken-3"
          @change="killFlex, removeFixedAmount"
          ></v-switch>
        </v-flex>
        <v-flex xs1>
          <v-tooltip top>
              <v-icon slot="activator" color="purple darken-3" class="fix_icon_less">info</v-icon>
              <span class="body-2">This amount will be displayed to your customer and Amazon fees will be ignored.
              </span>
            </v-tooltip>
        </v-flex>
      </v-layout>

      <v-layout row wrap>
        <v-flex xs4>                      
          <v-text-field
            :disabled="!fixed_enabled"
            type="number"
            color="purple darken-3"
            label="Fixed Rate Amount"
            v-model="fixed_rate_amount"
            prefix="$"
            class="move-up"
          ></v-text-field>
         </v-flex>
      </v-layout>

      <v-layout row wrap>
        <v-flex xs7>
          <v-switch label="Enable Free Shipping?" :disabled="!speed_enabled" v-model="free_enabled" color="purple darken-3"></v-switch>
        </v-flex>
      </v-layout>

      <v-layout row wrap>                    
        <v-flex xs8>                      
          <v-text-field
            :disabled="!free_enabled"
            type="number"
            color="purple darken-3"
            label="Order Amount to Qualify for Free Shipping"
            v-model="free_shipping_amount"
            class="move-up"
            prefix="$"
            @change="removeFreeAmount"
          ></v-text-field>
        </v-flex>
      </v-layout>

      <v-layout row wrap>
        <v-flex xs11>
          <v-btn 
            medium 
            dark 
            :disabled="!speed_enabled" 
            color="green lighten-1"
            @click="sendShipping()"
            >Save {{ speed }} Settings</v-btn>

          <v-btn 
            medium 
            outline 
            :disabled="!speed_enabled" 
            color="purple darken-3"
            @click="deleteShipping"
            >Delete {{ speed }} Settings</v-btn>
        </v-flex>                      
      </v-layout>                    
    </v-form>  
  </v-card>
</template>

<script>
import {dataShare} from '../packs/application.js';
import axios from 'axios';

export default {
  data: function() {
    return {
      speed: "Standard",
      icon_adjust: {'offset-xs1': false},
      icon_push_right: {'push-right': false},

      // [`${this.speed}_speed_enabled`]: false,
      speed_enabled: false,
      flex_enabled: false,
      fixed_enabled: false,  
      free_enabled: false,

      flex_switch_disabled: true,
      fixed_switch_disabled: true,

      fixed_rate_amount: "",
      free_shipping_amount: "",
      flex_above_or_below_amount: "",
      valid: true,

      percent_or_dollar: "",
      fee_type: ["$", "%"]
    };
  },
  created() {
    dataShare.$on('speed', (speed) => {
      this.speed = speed;
    });
    axios.get('https://bc-ship-trimakas.c9users.io/return_speed_info', {params: {speed: this.speed}}).then(response => {
      // this.speed = response.data.shipping_speed;
      this.speed_enabled = true;
      // this.[`${this.speed}_speed_enabled`] = true;
      this.fixed_rate_amount = response.data.fixed_amount;
      this.fixed_enabled = response.data.fixed;
      this.flex_enabled = response.data.flex;
      this.flex_above_or_below_amount = response.data.flex_amount;
      this.percent_or_dollar = response.data.flex_dollar_or_percent;
      this.free_enabled = response.data.free;
      this.free_shipping_amount = response.data.free_shipping_amount;
    });
  },
  computed: {
    removeFlexAmount(){
      if(this.flex_enabled == false){
        this.flex_above_or_below_amount = "";
        this.percent_or_dollar = "";
      }
    },
    removeFixedAmount(){
      if(this.fixed_enabled == false){
        this.fixed_rate_amount = "";
      }
    },
    removeFreeAmount(){
      if(this.free_enabled == false){
        this.free_shipping_amount = "";
      }
    },
    pushIconRight() {
    if(this.$vuetify.breakpoint.mdAndDown){
      this.icon_push_right['push-right'] = true;
    }
    else{
      this.icon_push_right['push-right'] = false;
    }
    },
    moveIcon() {
    console.log(this.$vuetify.breakpoint.name);
    if(this.$vuetify.breakpoint.mdAndDown){
      this.icon_adjust['offset-xs1'] = true;
    }
    else{
      this.icon_adjust['offset-xs1'] = false;
    }
    },
    enableAndDisable(){
      if(this.speed_enabled == true){
        this.flex_switch_disabled = false;
        this.fixed_switch_disabled = false;
      }
      else{
        this.flex_switch_disabled = true;
        this.fixed_switch_disabled = true;
      }
    },
    killFixed(){
      if(this.flex_enabled == true){
        this.fixed_switch_disabled = true;
        this.fixed_rate_amount = "";
      }
      if(this.speed_enabled == true && this.flex_enabled == true){
        this.fixed_switch_disabled = true;
        this.fixed_enabled = false;
        this.fixed_rate_amount = "";

      }
      if(this.speed_enabled == true && this.flex_enabled == false){
        this.fixed_switch_disabled = false;
      }
    },
    killFlex(){
      if(this.fixed_enabled == true){
        this.flex_switch_disabled = true;
        this.above_or_below_amount = "";
      }
      if(this.speed_enabled == true && this.fixed_enabled == true){
        this.flex_switch_disabled = true;
        this.flex_enabled = false;
        this.above_or_below_amount = "";
        this.percent_or_dollar = "";

      }
      if(this.speed_enabled == true && this.fixed_enabled == false){
        this.flex_switch_disabled = false;
      }
    }  
    },
    methods: {
      sendShipping() {
        const shipping = {
          speed_type: this.speed,
          speed_enabled: this.speed_enabled,
          flex_enabled: this.flex_enabled,
          fixed_enabled: this.fixed_enabled,  
          free_enabled: this.free_enabled,
          fixed_rate_amount: this.fixed_rate_amount,
          free_shipping_amount: this.free_shipping_amount,
          standard_flex_above_or_below_amount: this.above_or_below_amount,
          percent_or_dollar: this.percent_or_dollar
        };
        let self = this;
        let speed_info = {bytestand_rate_info: shipping};
        axios.post('https://bc-ship-trimakas.c9users.io/save_shipping_info', speed_info).then(response => {
          console.log(this.response);
        });
      },
      deleteShipping() {
        const deleteSpeed = {
          speed_type: this.speed          
        };
        let self = this;
        let delete_speed = {bytestand_rate_info: deleteSpeed};
        axios.post('https://bc-ship-trimakas.c9users.io/delete_speed', delete_speed).then(response => {
          console.log(this.response);
        });       
      }
    }
};
</script>

<style>

.push_down {
  margin-top: 18px;
}

.fix_icon_less {
  margin-top: 5px;
  margin-left: -70px;
}


.fix_icon {
  margin-top: 5px;
  margin-left: -80px;
}
.move-up {
  margin-top: -18px;
}

.move-left {
  margin-left: -20px;
}

.push-right {
  margin-left: 10px;
}

</style>
```

Comment: I wonder how you are using a dynamic property like that. Maybe a computed property is what you needed?

Comment: @Psidom I don't think so, but I could be wrong. But I have 3 tabs that share the same component. The difference is the data within the component. For example `this.standard_speed` could be `on` while `this.priority_speed` could be `off`. Within the same component. If that makes any sense?

Comment: Ahh, maybe something like this jsfiddle? https://jsfiddle.net/Linusborg/Lb0tk4kr/5/

Comment: If the data is different for different tabs, then you probably better set data as a `props` and pass data to the component in each tab. But maybe if it's simply an `on` and `off` state, create a computed property that returns the name of turned on option? Something like `standard_speed` or `priority_speed`?

Comment: see that's the thing, its the same component in each tab, just different data. I'd like to change the data names dynamically, but I could always just do `standard_speed` and `priority_speed` but it triples the number of variables I have.. causing a bit of a mess

Comment: how the names ("standard", "priority"...) are dynamics and added ? by props or inputs (with v-model) ? or are the names hardcoded inside the component (like in your example: `speed: "Standard"`) ?

Comment: **I have 3 tabs that share the same component** - surely they are different instances of the same component class?

Comment: I went ahead and added all my code, hopefully it better explains what I'm trying to do. Basically I'm trying to pass different data to the same component, and trying to make the data element names unique so that I don't have to duplicate the `speed_details` component.

Comment: Maybe you look for something like this https://jsfiddle.net/Linusborg/Lb0tk4kr/5/ ?